# Sharing Internet Connection with policies

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet

Just wondering how I can share the internet on my Windows 7 x64 PC (wired via ethernet) over WiFi. I know this can be done with Connectify or ad hoc sharing, but I would like to apply rules for each client connected to my shared wifi.

- **Example 1** - I would like to stop clients from accessing The Pirate Bay or porn sites.
- **Example 2** - I would like to limit the client's internet bandwidth. My total bandwidth is 20MBit/s. If I had 4 clients connected I could limit them to 5MBit/s each.

Comment: fwiw, I'm not aware of any consumer-friendly way to do this. When I've seen this done it's always been a Linux box configured manually for routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bought a Linksys wrt54g router and installed tomato on it, this gives me all the functions above...  Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to run a proxy server.

Try [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), it has been around a long time and has a very good reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bryan, Im just worried I would have to manually configure all of the clients... The main point of doing this is because I have neighbours that want to use my internet connection (I have a 20mb connection paid for by my employer) so I dont want them abusing it but also I dont mind them using it for occasional browsing. I dont think they would be happy if I started changing settings on there pc's

Comment: This is a minor change of a setting in IE or Firefox.